# Assemble (static Site generator) With Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js, assemble

I want to create a site using [assemble](https://github.com/assemble/assemble), yeoman, and angularJS.
The plan is that assemble will handle content and AngularJS will handle dynamic content via a REST API. Are the two compatible, is this a good choice of architecture? My concern is with the templating engine Assemble uses (HandleBars) and whether it is compatible with AngularJS as they both seem to use {{}}. I have only started investigating but am struggling to find examples of people using a similar architecture. How do i scaffold with Yeoman?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the Handlebars syntax to differentiate from the Angular template syntax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601499/how-can-i-change-the-handlebars-syntax-to-differentiate-from-the-angular-templat)

Answer (score 3):

I'm doing something similar and to handle the issue with the template delimiters I use the angular interpolateProvider to change the delimiters for angular.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).config(function ($interpolateProvider) {

    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%}');

});
```

I'm not sure if you can configure Yeoman to automatically use the new delimiters when running some of the scaffolds, but I hope this helps separate your templates from the assemble templates.

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar for a client for a retail site, to create a basis, custom CMS.

Originally I had the idea that all the items for sale (the data i.e model) would be represented via the data files - a mix of .json and yaml. (At least the client could edit the yaml file with some ease as it is sort of human readable).

A later improvement was to allow the client to edit the stock via a webpage - rather than editing the data files directly - Angular was ideal for this to have a webapp that basically allowed editing the data / upload and transform images, etc via a much nicer interface.

Answer (score 1):

Assemble uses [Handlebars (among others)](https://github.com/assemble/assemble#what-is-assemble) to render templates, so you can [use its syntax](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#escaping) to escape Angular templates in a .hbs file, this way:

```
\{{ qty * cost | currency }}
```